# Block label margin-bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a margin to a radio label.  I've changed the display style to block and added a bottom margin but it does not seem to affect the spacing at all, and overlaps with subsequent elements.

[image: Div padding sets spacing]
[image: Label margin does nothing]

https://jsfiddle.net/wospyqah/

e.g.:

```
.slider-label {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I'm working on it, but `input` elements don't get a closing tag.

Comment: Removed them :)

Comment: `position: absolute;` removes an element from the flow of the DOM, so any padding or margin doesn't affect other elements on the page. Also, you have a `height: 22px` on `.radios-to-slider.medium` so elements later on the page are going to butt up against it if it's children are taller than 22px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `.radios-to-slider` class is set to use `position:relative`, which takes it out of the normal flow of the document. 
Instead of adding a bottom margin to that class, just add a top margin to the `divinput` class.

```
div.divinput {
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uuzw5cwe/1/

Comment: This will work fine (and I can add margins for subsequent input elements), but I'll still get spacing issues with sequential radios unless I add top margin to that as well, but then I'm back to the issue of needing to add enough margin to compensate for my longest label instead of having just enough margin.  Is there a resource you can point me to for (learning to do) re-working of label positioning that won't take it out of the DOM flow?

Comment: Why can't you just insert an empty `div` in between those rows and apply the margins to those divs?